# Get emit pass from RenderLayer

Tags: scripting, render-layers

I want to temporarily store the emit channel of the rendered image to a new image "EMIT". Looking through the manual, I found `bpy.types.RenderLayer.passes`, but I do not know how to use it. I wrote `bpy.types.RenderLayer.passes["Emit"]`, but it produces an error:

> AttributeError: type object 'RenderLayer' has no attribute 'passes'

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer. I hope you don't mind. If I changed the meaning of what you wanted to say in any way, please edit the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use compositing and output the Emit pass to a file:

[image]

It is possible to enable compositing nodes and add a File Output node to it with Python as well if you needed that.